# Ipad mini won't register for imessage

Tags: ipad, messages

My wife and I just bought two Ipad mini 2's. We each have our own Apple IDs but when we try to use Imessage to send each other a message it states that the other's ID is not registered with Imessage. But I can send and receive messages with other ipads.

Comment: Is this the case even after verifying that iMessage has been tuned on in the settings? (Settings > Messages > iMessage slider set to on. Green)

Comment: yes, I've toggled it on and off for both, I've updated them to the latest IOS. I've done what the apple site has recommend for other problems with Imessage.

Comment: What's it say under Settings > Messages > Send & Receive?